# PHP to print using dot-matrix printers

Tags: php, printing, dot-matrix

I am working on a project that will end up printing receipts, my client uses a dot-matrix printer (some old version). He will need a system where receipt printing will be fast i.e. time efficient, and not opening a dialog box and choosing a printer...moreover the printer will be shared through a network.

The main problem is that all this should be done using PHP. the following are some thoughts of solutions.

- Design a php script to write data to a text file then print the text file using a remote printer

-the problem is that I am having a hard time getting server side printing from PHP. Logically it seems to work.

Platform         =====> WIN XP

Printer Location =====> Main server on a LAN N/W

Comment: Write proper English if you want to be taken seriously.

Comment: okay let me prase it properly.....thnx

Comment: This question doesn't make any sense.

Comment: okey its edited, sorry for the english there

Comment: Easy guys, not everyone's first language is english, or even their second.

Comment: the_forgotten_guru: You should edit your question to show some more details about OS / Platform / where the printer is etc.

Comment: Thnx for the cmments......any answer?

Comment: @guru It's been 30 minutes, give it time :)

Comment: php is for web programming. printing receipt on a specific dot-matrix printer is in no way related to web. so why php?

Comment: the system i designed is in php, so the client is saying that printng after the recpt is displyd on screen, in html, is time wasting! so he needs just to press enter and the recpt prints out from the dot-matrix printer

Answer (score 2):

What's the intended workflow before the user hit's enter?
What's the make and model of printer? This is important so that we can see if it needs any fancy escape codes sent to it?
Usually if you're printing then it would be sent from the client machine.
If printing from the server the data needs to be either sent to the server or needs to already be there and accessible. Is it already there in a database? Or are you sending a webform?
You say RCPT, is this a receipt?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so if you have the text file created on the server you should be able to copy the text file to lpt1: or 2: or whatever device it's defined as.
You need to know what the file's named as, or you could pass it on, but how about:

```
exec('c:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c START C:\some_dir\print_me.bat');
```